MS Project Server - how to insert a new child entry into an existing Enterprise Custom Lookup Table using the REST API (or JSOM)?
Through much trial and error, I was able to figure out how to create custom Enterprise Lookup Tables, and populate them with entries, using the Project Server REST API.
I now need to be able to add entries to the existing Lookup Tables, also using the REST API.
If it's a flat list, it's easy because I can get the SortIndex of the last entry, and just start adding new entries after that. (ICYMI, SortIndex is a required parameter for creating new Lookup Table entries.)
However, if it's a hierarchical table, I run into a problem if I need to insert a new child entry under a parent entry that is not the last parent entry.  For instance, given this hierarchy:



Level
Value




1
Parent A


2
     Child A.1


2
     Child A.2


1
Parent B


2
     Child B.1


2
     Child B.2



I can easily add new children under Parent B, but I can't insert Child A.3, and the problem has to do with the SortIndex.
Even in a hierarchical table, the SortIndex values are "flat"-ly incremental, like this:



SortIndex
Level
Value




1
1
Parent A


2
2
     Child A.1


3
2
     Child A.2


4
1
Parent B


5
2
     Child B.1


6
2
     Child B.2



So if I get the highest SortIndex of 6, then try to add an entry Child A.3 specifying the ParentId of the ID of the Parent A entry, but SortIndex of 7, then I get an error:

403 - Forbidden: PJClientCallableException: LookupTableSortOrderMustComeBeforeParentNextSiblingSortOrder

Ok, that seems to make sense, it seems to be saying that the SortIndex for Child A.3 has to come before Parent A's next sibling (Parent B) SortIndex. Makes sense, that would keep the flat incremental-ness of the overall sort order.
So then if I try to coax it to insert the entry at the correct SortIndex of 4, it still throws the same error. If I try "inserting" it at SortIndex 3, then I get

403 - Forbidden: PJClientCallableException: LookupTableSortOrderIndexDuplicate

So then I tried "making room" for the insertion by working backwards through the list of entries to increment each one's SortIndex to be one higher until I work down to 4 (Parent B), make that entry's SortIndex 5, and then theoretically I can add a new child entry under Parent A with SortIndex 4, which will be before the parent's next sibling sort index, and will not be a duplicate.
However when I tried this, despite getting a 204 response (indicating success) for the first MERGE edit request (changing Child B.2 sort index from 6 to 7), each subsequent request threw the "duplicate sort index" error, and poking around, it looks like the change did not take, Child B.2 still has a SortIndex of 6.
So how the heck are you supposed to add new entries as children in a hierarchical lookup table?
I am primarily using the REST API, but I do have the JSOM (PS.js) library loaded and can work with that if need be.
